# Dealing with dynamic value types with Swift and Codeable

Tags: swift, generics

So i am trying to decode a JSON via a Codeable model object. One of the properties, say `series_id`, can either be an integer or a string. If empty, it is `null`.

How do I handle that using the decodable option in Swift? I currently have:

```
struct ContentItem: Codable {
    let content_id: String?
    let series_id: String?
    let rank: Int
    let score: Float

}
```

In my main code I do:

```
do {
        let object = try self.decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(.success(object))
        }
} catch {
...
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `enum` for that. So it could be either a `String` or an `Int` or `Unknown`:

```
extension ContentItem {
    enum SeriesId: Codable {
        case text(String)
        case number(Int)

        case unknown
    }
}
```

Then you can implement as a `Decodable`:

```
extension ContentItem.SeriesId {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let text = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .text(text)
        } else if let number = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .number(number)
        } else {
            assertionFailure("Unknown SeriesId type")
            self = .unknown
        }
    }
}
```

**Note that** you can expand this to manage whatever *Empty* means (Since it could be a number as well and empty number is unknown).

Also you can expand it to make it encodable too:

```
extension ContentItem.SeriesId {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .text(let text): try container.encode(text)
        case .number(let number): try container.encode(number)
        case .unknown: throw NSError(domain: "Unknown case is not encodable", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

So you only need to change the type of the `series_id`:

```
struct ContentItem: Codable {
    let content_id: String?
    let series_id: SeriesId?
    let rank: Int
    let score: Float
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Worked like a charm. So good to be able to learn more on how versatile Codable is

Comment: `extension ContentItem.SeriesId {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self = try .text(container.decode(String.self))
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            self = try .number(container.decode(Int.self))
        } catch {
            assertionFailure("Unknown SeriesId type")
            self = .unknown
        }
    }
}`

Comment: btw your encoding method is incomplete `case .unknown: try container.encode(self)`

Comment: I have added that case.

Comment: So i don't want to return an enum but an actual string in this case. That is cast to a string. Any way to do that?

Comment: This thread is old and your question is  a little bit different with the original one. Please ask a new question and link it here in the comment so I can help you with that my friend :) @Doz